# How to make selector choose div class and with tag name of p?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am kind of stuck right now. I am trying to make my script choose all paragraph inside a div class of change but I don't really understand how to do it. The html looks something like this in the body

```
<body>
<div id="top" class="change">
<p> Microsoft </p>
<p> Apple </p>
<p> Sony </p>
</div>

<div id="middle">
<p> Disney </p>
<p> Nintendo </p>
<p> Sony </p>
</div>

<div id="bottom" class="change">
<p> Ice</p>
<p> Tea</p>
<p> Water</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I am trying to make it so when the mouse cursor touches anything that has a class of change in a paragraph, it will change the color to a color of my choice but I don't know how to do it with selectors with pure javascript. This is the current code I have but it is not working. I can only use javascript

```
var fontChange = document.getElementsByClass("change").getElementsByTagName("p");

for (let i = 0; i < changeFont.length; i++) {
    changeFont[i].onmouseover=function() {
        this.style.color = "red";
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < changeFont.length; i++) {
    changeFont[i].onmouseout=function() {
        this.style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried onblur? And using a selector...

Comment: you mean, you want to change the font color on hover? or on click?

Comment: just on hover but I want it to only hover on the div classes of change only so only div top/bottom and not div middle

Comment: I have a better and a lot easier solution for you. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function `getElementsByClass`, it's `getElementsByClassName`.

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection (see [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)), you have to index it to use `getElementsByTagName` on the elements that it returns.

```
var fontChange = [];
var change = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
for (var i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {
    var paras = [].slice.call(change[i].getElementsByTagName("p"));
    fontChange.concat(paras);
}
```

Or you could just use `querySelectorAll`

```
var fontChange = document.querySelectorAll(".change p");
```

You also have a typo. You set the variable `fontChange`, but then use `changeFont` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want without javascript, just add this code to your css

```
.change p:hover {
    color: red;
 }
```